# 'Freeze first column' half transparent in Power BI Report Builder

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi, ssrs-tablix, reportbuilder

When building a table in Power BI report builder I need to 'freeze' the first column. I have done this using tablix properties and ticking 'Keep header visible while scrolling'. I have also made the tablix background white rather than 'No Color'.

This works great when I run the report in Report Builder. I then publish the report to web service and it half works...

The top half of the table works great but as you scroll down and across the first column becomes transparent?!

Any tips/ideas as to why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: Help understand the question better with screenshots.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't really screenshot as it's sensitive data